# Combine labels and allowframebreaks in beamer class

Tags: latex, tex, beamer

For my latex beamer presentations, I have used a labeling system with short, long, and both, to quickly switch between short presentations and longer ones.

To do so, I use the code 
`\includeonlyframes{both,short}` (for a short presentation, and likewise `\includeonlyframes{both,long}` for a long one) in the preamble, and put a label to each slide like this:

```
\begin{frame}[label=both]
```

This system has served me relatively well in the past, but it has also created some problems. The particular one I am trying to solve is that my references exceed one slide. I tried to use allowframebreaks to solve this, so here is the code for my reference slide:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,label=both]    
\frametitle{References}

\tiny    
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}    
    \bibliography{references}

\end{frame}
```

What happens now is that the first reference slide is displayed as it's supposed to, but the remaining ones aren't part of the pdf. I guess what is happening is that the label is only applied to the first slide, so due to my `\includeonlyframes` command in the preamble, the remaining reference slides are produced, but not included in the pdf. Does anyone have an idea how I could get around this problem?

Also, this is my first post here, so please let me know if something is unclear/badly explained etc.

Edit: Here's a minimal working example. I usually use natbib, but that didn't work with the example bibliography I used here. The issue still occurs, so I don't think natbib has anyhting to do with it.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
%\usepackage{natbib}
\includeonlyframes{both,short}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=both] 
\frametitle{Frametitle} 
Some content for both presentations 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=short] 
\frametitle{Frametitle}
Some content for a short presentation 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=long] 
\frametitle{Frametitle}
Some content for a long presentation 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=long] 
\frametitle{Frametitle}
Some more content for a long presentation 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,label=both] 
\frametitle{References}
 %\tiny 
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\bibliography{references} \bibliography{xampl}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a compilable minimal working example instead of code fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a similar approach as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289637 and update it to use the current implementation of `\beamer@@@@frame`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@@@@frame<#1>[#2]{%
  \framewidth\textwidth
  \beamer@savemode%
  \gdef\beamer@mode{\mode<all>}%
  \def\beamer@frametemplate{}%
  \def\beamer@againname{}%
  \def\beamer@undolabels{}%
  \def\beamer@cramped{}%
  \def\beamer@displaybreak{}%
  \setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
  \beamer@autobreakcount=0\relax%
  \beamer@autobreaklastheight=16000pt%
  \beamer@zoomcount=0\relax%
  \beamer@noframenumberingfalse%
  \beamer@containsverbatimfalse%
  \beamer@isfragilefalse%
  \beamer@autobreakfalse%
  \beamer@shrinkfalse%
  \beamer@plainframefalse%
  \global\advance\beamer@zoomframecount by1\relax%
  \csname beamer@dosecondmode\beamer@defaultdosecondmode\endcsname%
  \ifbeamer@centered\setkeys{beamerframe}{c}\else\setkeys{beamerframe}{t}\fi%
  \setkeys{beamerframe}{environment=frame}%
  \setkeys{beamerframe}{#2}%
  \beamer@frametemplate%
  \ifbeamer@noframenumbering%
    \ifbeamer@isfragile%Fragile frames will be processed twice
      \stepcounter{framenumber}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \stepcounter{framenumber}%do not set \label here - it interferes with AtBegin*
  \fi%
  {\let\@elt\beamer@savecounter\beamer@overlaycounterresets}
  \gdef\beamer@framestartpage{}%
  \gdef\beamer@whichframes{#1}%
  \ifx\beamer@framerestriction\@undefined\else% restriction stuff
    \expandafter\beamer@checkifinlist\beamer@framerestriction\relax%
  \fi%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture%
  \else%
    \gdef\beamer@whichframes{all:0}%
  \fi%
  \ifx\beamer@againname\@empty%
    \beamer@slideinframe=0\relax%
    \beamer@anotherslidefalse%
    \beamer@masterdecode{\beamer@whichframes}%
    \ifbeamer@anotherslide%
        \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@doseveralframes%
      \ifbeamer@containsverbatim%
        \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@dosingleframe%
      \fi%
      \ifbeamer@autobreak%
        \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@autobreakframe%
      \fi%
      \ifbeamer@isfragile%
        \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@doexternalframe%
      \fi%
    \else% no slides in frame
      \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@donoframe%
    \fi%
  \else% again mode
    \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@doseveralframes%
    \ifbeamer@isfragile%
      \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@doexternalframe%
    \fi%
    \ifbeamer@containsverbatim
      \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@dosingleframe
    \fi
    \beamer@slideinframe=0\relax%
    \beamer@anotherslidefalse%
    {\beamer@masterdecode{\beamer@whichframes}}%
    \message{^^J^^J \beamer@againname:\beamer@whichframes ^^J^^J}
    \ifbeamer@anotherslide%
      \message{^^J^^J \beamer@againname:I am Here ^^J^^J}
      \ifbeamer@autobreak%
        \let\beamer@howtotreatframe\beamer@autobreakframe%
      \fi%
    \fi    
  \fi%
  \beamer@howtotreatframe}
\makeatother

\includeonlyframes{both,long}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,label=both]   
\nocite{*} 
\frametitle{References}

%\tiny    
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}    
    \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=long]
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really far from what I'm currently using, so if there's a fix that involves less changes that would be great.

Comment: @LukasAltermatt Can you specify what you mean with "looks really far from what I'm currently using"? Is it too much code or is the output not what you expect?

Comment: @LukasAltermatt Well, you want to change some basic mechanism of beamer to add something that was declined by the beamer maintainer (https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/265) You ought to accept that this takes a bit of code. Btw `allowframebrakes` is not a command, it is a key

Comment: Ok, I have to apologize for not looking at your comment more carefully this morning. I thought what you were suggesting was using a different package, but I understand now what the code does. I have to say it is a lot of code to add for something that mainly bothered me stylistically (nobody ever looks at the references slide anyway), but it does the trick, so thanks a lot!

Comment: @LukasAltermatt No need to apologise :) About the nobody-ever-looks-at-the-reference-slide problem: Personally I would not use such a slide, but use the `biblatex` package instead. It has the very useful `\footcite` and `\footfullcite` commands, which will add the references as footnote on the slide they are mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had a quick look at the biblatex package, but it seems to require a bunch of changes compared to my approach. In my field (economics), the author-year format, and sometimes expanded by the short name of the journal, is always used, and people in the audience will know from that which paper is meant - thus, nobody looks at the reference page.